# IOS/Objective-C/Core-data: how to get object from objectID

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, objectid

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035057/how-to-get-core-data-object-from-specific-object-id) suggests that to get an object from the objected, you use a method such as this:

```
-(NSManagedObject *)objectRegisteredForID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID
```

or

```
-(NSManagedObject *)objectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID
```

This may be a dumb question but how do you call these methods? With the MOC, managed object and other objects involved, am finding this very confusing and not succeeding in calling either method.

This is giving a 'use of undeclared identifier' error, for example:

```
NSManagedObject *object = objectRegisteredForID:self.moID;
```

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Both of these methods, and the third method mentioned in the link, are all declared in NSManagedObjectContext. Hence you would call these methods on NSManagedObjectContext.

If using private conncurrency be sure you are in the context's block

Comment: https://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/core-data-overview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both are methods of the `NSManagedObjectContext` therefore you need to call this method on an `NSManagedObjectContext` instance where this object is in.

See also https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/objectWithID:

Comment: NSManagedObject *object = [self.managedObjectContext objectRegisteredForID:_moID]; is working